# Decoding multiple DER certificates on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I've got a CFDataRef that contains a DER-encoded X.509 certificate that I can use to create a SecCertificateRef like so:

```
CFDataRef binaryDataRef = ... // from third party
SecCertificateRef certRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData (NULL, binaryDataRef);
```

However in some cases my CFData can contain *multiple* certs (a cert chain) that have been concatenated together using i2d_X509 by third-party code.

Is there a call on iOS similar to SecCertificateCreateWithData that can decode all of the certificates? SecCertificateCreateWithData is just giving me the first cert.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I can use d2i_X509 to figure out where each cert is, and it handily adjusts the pointer to the next one in the array.

```
CFArrayRef nmCopyEncodedCertificates(CFDataRef derDataRef) {
    CFMutableArrayRef certs = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

    if (derDataRef) {        
        CFIndex bytesRemaining = CFDataGetLength(derDataRef);
        const unsigned char *pDerData = CFDataGetBytePtr(derDataRef);
        const unsigned char *pCurCertBegin = pDerData;
        X509 *certX509 = NULL;

        while ((certX509 = d2i_X509(NULL, &pDerData, bytesRemaining)) != NULL &&    // increments pDerData to next cert
               bytesRemaining > 0) {
            X509_free(certX509);
            long len = pDerData - pCurCertBegin;
            if (len > 0) {
                CFDataRef certData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, pCurCertBegin, len);
                if (certData) {
                    SecCertificateRef certRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData (kCFAllocatorDefault, certData);
                    if (certRef) {
                        CFArrayAppendValue(certs, certRef);
                        CFRelease(certRef);
                    }
                    CFRelease(certData);
                }
                bytesRemaining -= len;
                pCurCertBegin = pDerData;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return certs;
}
```